# Hacking wall wart as a USB charging station

Tags: usb, charger

I would like to modify an old power supply to have a USB A female adapter so that I could use it to charge any device.

I plan to split out the power lines from an adapter that is:
Input: 100-240V - 1.0A 47-63Hz
Output: 5.0V 3.8A max

I know that some devices like the data lines to be high, but for now I'm focusing on the power required and any pitfalls there.

Am I correct in calculating that I could add four USB female jacks to this power supply and there would be enough power to charge most devices with them. I just need to connect each jacks pins to the correct lines.

Would there be any issues with this that I am missing?

EDIT: Upon further reading I've noted that a 600mA fuse on each line would be good protection if a device draws too much.
Also decoupling capacitors for each line would protect lines from each other.

Comment: You can get a powered USB hub for about five dollars. This project is not worth the effort.

Comment: I can build this for free using components I have lying around and learn a bit more about circuits. It's worth the effort to me.

Comment: I'd bump the fuse up a bit, since some devices may try to pull up to 2A or so.

Comment: I would consider allowing at least 1A at the port to allow newer devices to charge faster.

Comment: http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/resettable-wire-ended-fuses/0506965/ 
These have a 2.2A trip and then a 1A hold. Which would mean even after tripping newer devices would be able to get a reasonable charge. Yeah?

Comment: Many usb devices expect a certain voltage on the data lines but not always 5v.  Adafruit's mintyboost tutorial has some details on that.  Would link but am on my phone, google will find it.

Answer (score 1):

Many devices won't properly charge from a 5V supply, they need a USB host (or power controller) to supply the correct command first.

The original USB spec (USB2.0) gave only 100mA per port until the device identifies itself and provides it's power needs to the host.

Then the current is limited to 500mA.  USB3.0 increased this to 1.5A, again through negotiation.  Some devices adhere to this spec so won't charge (at more than 100mA) until a host tells them so.  Later specs (as well as deviations from the spec) again increase the available current through negotiation for battery charging by using the data lines as power lines to increase the current capacity of the  wire.

Basicly this means that sometimes pluging some devices into a wall wart (PSU) will only change very slowly (if at all) unless that PSU has a USB host or power controller inside it.

I have an Asus tablet that certainly behaves like this.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a diode for each line, series with the mentioned fuses. Imagine some usb devices connected to the charger while the charger is unplugged. This could result in batteries draining if they don't have internal protection circuits, and many low end devices lack such protection.